# Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<GMap.NET.PointLagLng> to System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Point>

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm using GMaps.NET and GMaps.WindowsPresentation in a WPF application. One of the classes that comes with GMaps presentation is GMapPolygon and  a function called CreatePath. I'm trying to test adding a line between two or multiple points using this function but I'm getting the error when parsing a list of points. Must it be a certain type of list or am I missing something.

There are no examples that I can find of plotting a line between two points in using Windows Presentation but there are for Windows Forms

This is what I'm trying to do now:

```
 List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
            points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.866383, 2.323575));
            points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.863868, 2.321554));
            points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.861017, 2.330030));
            points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.863727, 2.331918));
            GMapPolygon SectorPolygon = new GMapPolygon(points);
            SectorPolygon.CreatePath( points,true);
```

This is the function I'm parsing to:

```
public virtual Path CreatePath(List<Point> localPath, bool addBlurEffect)
      {
         // Create a StreamGeometry to use to specify myPath.
         StreamGeometry geometry = new StreamGeometry();

         using(StreamGeometryContext ctx = geometry.Open())
         {
            ctx.BeginFigure(localPath[0], true, true);

            // Draw a line to the next specified point.
            ctx.PolyLineTo(localPath, true, true);
         }

         // Freeze the geometry (make it unmodifiable)
         // for additional performance benefits.
         geometry.Freeze();

         // Create a path to draw a geometry with.
         Path myPath = new Path();
         {
            // Specify the shape of the Path using the StreamGeometry.
            myPath.Data = geometry;

            if(addBlurEffect)
            {
               BlurEffect ef = new BlurEffect();
               {
                  ef.KernelType = KernelType.Gaussian;
                  ef.Radius = 3.0;
                  ef.RenderingBias = RenderingBias.Performance;
               }

               myPath.Effect = ef;
            }

            myPath.Stroke = Brushes.MidnightBlue;
            myPath.StrokeThickness = 5;
            myPath.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
            myPath.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Triangle;
            myPath.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Square;

            myPath.Fill = Brushes.AliceBlue;

            myPath.Opacity = 0.6;
            myPath.IsHitTestVisible = false;
         }
         return myPath;
      }
```

Comment: If you can fix some of the typos in your question it would be easier to read ("covert", "PointLagLng")

Comment: This is the basic way that the C# language helps you to identify brain-bugs.  You can't just convert a latitude+longitude to a Point, the conversion requires you to consider what map projection you want.  There are many to choose from.